# In visual studio 2017, why won't xamarin app controls (button, editText) show up?

Tags: android-layout, xamarin, android-emulator, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I just built my first Xamarin app using Visual Studio 2017.
I built the main app from the template and it ran fine.

Now, I added two controls to the layout (a button and an EditText) which render fine in the design view but do not show up when the app runs.

Here's the layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button
            android:text="DoWork"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/doWorkButton" />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight=".5"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/workText" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here's what it looks like in design view:

[image: design view renders properly]

Here's what it looks like after running it.
I've tried running numerous times in debug and non-debug mode but it never shows the controls.[image: running - no controls]

**EDIT 1**

Additional things I've tried.
I just did a manual uninstall of the package using command-line adb:

```
c:\>adb uninstall FirstXam.FirstXam <ENTER>
Success*
```

*Success is how adb uinstall reports that it worked.

I went and had VS 2017 deploy again, but the controls still don't show up.
:(

**EDIT 2**

I altered the string displayed at the top of the app in an attempt to verify if anything is changing and it fails too.

You can see where I've altered the `ApplicationName` string on the right, but again after building, deploying and running again, the changes do not show up.
It's beginning to feel like I'm debugging Visual Studio 2017. :(

[image: applicationname string altered]

**EDIT 3**

This is now at new levels : Entirely Ludicrous

I deployed found the signed apk in the debug directory and deployed it to my phone (physical hardware).

The app installed just fine -- though it required complete network access and the ability to write to my SD card, which is interesting to have by default.

When I ran the app, it showed the UI just long enough that I could see that the controls were missing and the title bar shows up with the original string text "FirstXam".

Then the app crashes.

Comment: I tested your code both using VS 2015 and and VS 2017, it works fine, did you `SetContentView` in the `MainActivity`? Just with your posted code, I can't know what problem cause your app's crash.

Comment: As soon as I read your comment and saw "did you 'SetContentView' in the MainActivity" I knew that was the problem.  Why does VStudio comment that line out by default?  Oy!